# Frame # not found when using Puppeteer

Tags: c#, .net, automation, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I'm having issues with Puppeteer, I am trying to type in a textbox that is in an IFrame.
I have created a simple repo with a code snippet, this one contains an IFrame with a tweet from Twitter.

```
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);
var launchOptions = new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = false,
    DefaultViewport = null
};
launchOptions.Args = new[] { "--disable-web-security", "--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process" };
ChromeDriver = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(launchOptions);

page = await ChromeDriver.NewPageAsync();
await page.GoToAsync(Url, new NavigationOptions { WaitUntil = new WaitUntilNavigation[] { WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle0 } });
var selectorIFrame = "#twitter_iframe";
var frameElement1 = await page.WaitForSelectorAsync(selectorIFrame);
var frame1 = await frameElement1.ContentFrameAsync();
var frameContent1 = await frame1.GetContentAsync();
```

`var frame1 = await frameElement1.ContentFrameAsync();` fails with  *`Frame # not found`*, see image with error below.

[image]

Versions:

- PuppeteerSharp 7.0
- .Net Framework 6
- [Git](https://github.com/raul-junc-lateral/Puppeteer) example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable some of the security features that can be disabled when [launching puppeteer](https://github.com/christian-fei/mega-scraper/blob/master/lib/browser/get-puppeteer-options.js).

Check in puppeteer chrome://flags/ in case there's something blocking iframe access, maybe is insecure content or maybe you have to be explicit about isolation trial.

My 2 cents on this, it should allow it to access it from non secure

```
Args = new[]
    {
        "--disable-web-security",
        "--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process,BlockInsecurePrivateNetworkRequests",
        "--disable-site-isolation-trials"
    }
```